# Searching for a question about random walk

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Hi all! Sorry if this is an inappropriate use of meta.

I am trying to find a question that was asked within the last few months, which was about a hitting time for a certain random walk.  I believe it was a random walk on the integers which was able to move by more than 1.  The question was about the time to reach a certain value, and it was made complicated by the fact that the process might jump over the value without actually reaching it.

I searched every term I could think of, and browsed the last several months of questions tagged "probability", but I cannot find it.  If anyone remembers the question more specifically and can point me to it, I'd appreciate it.

Note: It's also possible the question was on MathOverflow instead of here.  I searched there as well without result.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this walk a silly walk? :-)

Comment: Is there a result of your interest coming up in http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=A1X&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=hitting+time+++random+walk+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq= ? This is by searching "hitting time   random walk site:math.stackexchange.com" in google. Similarly, it can be searched in mathoverflow.com

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, but no, I didn't see it there.  I am not sure that the words "random walk" or "hitting time" were actually used in the question, I just remember that this was the essence.

Comment: I don't get the new tag.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, the Ravens did win the Superbowl XLVII, and they [just visited Obama](http://www.ctpost.com/news/article/Obama-congratulates-Super-Bowl-champion-Ravens-4579655.php) for that reason, but ... yeah, I don't get the tag either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry about that, there was a suggestion in another question that the new "edit tags" button existed so that 10K users could retag without bumping.  I couldn't find an official word so I thought I would test.  Apparently it still gets bumped :(  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I forgive you my son.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more fruitful searching, I think I must have been thinking of [A probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37222).  I thought it was further back than that.  My memory must be going...

Comment: I can't blame you, that title is awfully nondescript.

Comment: Why not edit the title to contain the words you searched for?

Comment: The question you linked to certainly could use a better title...